# $\mathcal L(V_1 \times \cdots \times V_m,W) \approx \mathcal L(V_1,W) \times \cdots \times \mathcal L(V_m,W)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

> Suppose $V_1, \dots, V_m, W$ are vector spaces$^\dagger$.  Prove that $\mathcal L(V_1 \times \cdots \times V_m,W)$ and $\mathcal L(V_1,W) \times \cdots \times \mathcal L(V_m,W)$ are isomorphic vector spaces.

I'm having some trouble with this one.  If the vector spaces were finite-dimensional I could try proving that each has the same dimension, but the question doesn't specify that they're finite-dimensional spaces.

It seems like maybe I need to construct the isomorphism. So I'd need some linear mapping $$\big((v_1,\dots, v_m)\mapsto w\big)\mapsto (v_1 \mapsto w_1, \dots, v_m\mapsto w_m)$$ but TBH I'm getting a little confused from my own notation here.

Could someone give a hint as to how to get started on this exercise?

---

<sup>$\dagger$: The running assumption is that we're talking about $\Bbb R$- or $\Bbb C$-vector spaces, if that's relevant.</sup>

Comment: Notice that your attempt does not make sense, for $w_1$ does not mean anything.

Comment: Well, I didn't specify, but $w, w_1, \dots, w_m$ should all be elements of $W$ while $v_i$ should specifically be an element of $V_i$.

Comment: Yes. That does not make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

- Do it for two factors first.
- If $f:V_1\times V_2\to W$ is a linear map, then you can consider the map $f_1:v\in V_1\mapsto f(v,0)\in W$ and, similarly, a map $f_2:V_2\to W$ constructed from $f$. In this way you can produce a function $$\Phi:f\in L(V_1\times V_2,W)\mapsto (f_1,f_2)\in L(V_1,W)\times L(V_2,W).$$ Show that it does what you want.

Comment: Awesome-sauce!  Thanks!

Comment: How to prove that this map is injective?  Notive that if we have finite dimension we could have problems.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4447891/a-isomorphism-between-mathcallu-v-and-mathcallu-times-mathcall/4447896#4447896.

Answer (score 4):

The natural linear surjections
$$p_i:V_1\times\dots\times V_m\to V_i,\;(v_1,\dots,v_m)\mapsto v_i$$
and injections
$$q_i:V_i\to V_1\times\dots\times V_m,\;u\mapsto(0,\dots,0,u,0,\dots,0)$$
(where $u$ is the $i$-th component in $(0,\dots,0,u,0,\dots,0)$) satisfy
$$\sum_{i=1}^mq_i\circ p_i(v_1,\dots,v_m)=(v_1,\dots,v_m),\quad p_i\circ q_j(u)=\begin{cases}u&\text{if }i=j,\\0&\text{if }i\ne j.
\end{cases}$$

Therefore, the two maps
$$F:\mathcal L(V_1 \times \dots \times V_m,W)\to\mathcal L(V_1,W) \times \dots \times \mathcal L(V_m,W),\;f\mapsto(f\circ q_1,\dots,f\circ q_m)$$
$$G:\mathcal L(V_1,W) \times \dots \times \mathcal L(V_m,W)\to \mathcal L(V_1 \times \dots \times V_m,W),\;(f_1,\dots,f_m)\mapsto\sum_{i=1}^mf_i\circ p_i$$
are mutually inverse isomorphisms, since they are linear by construction, and satisfy
$$(G\circ F)(f)=f,\quad(F\circ G)(f_1,\dots,f_m)=(f_1,\dots,f_m).$$

Comment: Is there a difference between "mutually inverse" and just "inverse?

Comment: I found adding "mutually" makes the sentencse clearer. Each one is the inverse *of the other one*. "Being inverse" alone makes no sense. @xoux