# A isomorphism between $\mathcal{L}(U,V)$ and $\mathcal{L}(U) \times \mathcal{L}(V)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations, banach-spaces

Let $U$, $V$ be two Banach spaces and define the spaces
$$
\mathcal{L}(U\times V) = \{T : U\times V \rightarrow U\times V : T \text{ is linear and bounded}\},
$$
$$
\mathcal{L}(U) = \{T : U \rightarrow U : T \text{ is linear and  bounded}\},
$$
and
$$
\mathcal{L}(V) = \{T : V \rightarrow V : T \text{ is linear and  bounded}\}.
$$
I'm trying to identify the spaces $\mathcal{L}(U\times V)$ and $\mathcal{L}(U) \times \mathcal{L}(V)$ by a isomorphism.

**What I tried:**
Define the map  $\Psi : \mathcal{L}(U\times V) \rightarrow \mathcal{L}(U) \times \mathcal{L}(V)$ by
$$
\Psi(T) = (T_1(\cdot, 0), T_2(0,\cdot)),
$$
where $T = (T_1, T_2)$. I dont know if this is the best map to define. I have trouble to prove it is injective.  Any help to prove or counterexample would be very welcome.

Comment: What is $(T_1,T_2)$? And how do you know that every element of $\mathcal L(U \times V)$ is of this form?

Comment: Given $T  \in \mathcal{L}(U\times V)$, as we have $T(u,v) \in U \times V$ for each $(u,v) \in U \times V$, we can say that there's T_1,T_2 from $U\times V$ in $U, V$ respectivly such that $T(u,v) = (T_1(u,v), T_2(u,v))$. That's what I tgouht.

Comment: A  better guess is $$L(U\times V) \simeq $$$$\simeq L(U)\times L(V)\times L (U,V)\times L(V,U)$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This statement is not true, as can be simply seen from the case where $U, V$ are two finite dimensional spaces of dimensions $m, n$ respectively.

In that case, any linear operator is bounded and hence $\mathcal L(U)$ can be identified, via the choice of a basis, with the space of $m \times m$ matrices. Therefore $\mathcal L(U)$ has dimension $m^2$.

For the same reason, $\mathcal L(V)$ has dimension $n^2$ and $\mathcal L(U\times V)$ has dimension $(m + n)^2$. It is then clear that the dimensions don't match.

Comment: Thank you very much! What about if we suppose they have infinity dimension ?